# What is the advantage of adaptors over lambda expression in sigc++?

Tags: c++, lambda, glibmm, libsigc++

### Background

Suppose I have the following template function to parse an input parameter:

```
template <typename T>
bool my_parse(const Glib::ustring& data, T& storage) {
  // Logic: data >> storag
}
```

But for working with `Glib::OptionGroup`, I need the following signature for a callback function (slot),

```
bool parse(const Glib::ustring& X, const Glib::ustring& data, bool Y);
```

where `X` and `Y` are irrelevant and the second parameter corresponds to the first parameter in `my_parse`. Now in order to drop the two unwanted parameters and inject the `storage`-parameter, I can use adaptors as follows:

```
unsigned int my_storage;
auto my_func = sigc::ptr_fun<bool, const Glib::ustring&, size_t&>(&my_parse);
auto my_slot = sigc::hide<0>(sigc::hide(sigc::bind(my_func, my_storage)));
og.add_entry(my_option_entry, my_slot);
```

The same can be achieved using a lambda expression, in which case the code reads:

```
auto my_lambda = [&](const Glib::ustring& name, const Glib::ustring& value, bool) {
  std::ignore = name;
  return my_parse(value, my_storage);
};
og.add_entry(my_option_entry, my_lambda);
```

### Question

IMO, the second piece of code is much more readable and can be readily understood without looking up `bind` and `hide` in the documentation. Is there any advantage in using the adaptor solution?

Comment: Most credible C++ libraries predate C++11; lambda was an academic paradigm under discussion back then. You always needed those adapters as primary solutions. Now you can many of those function adapters and just use lambdas. But take care if the library implements reflection/metadata(like Qt does) through those adapters.

Comment: So I suppose the answer is something along "There seems to be no advantage in `libsigc++` but in general, a library may implement special functionality in adaptors that won't be executed when using custom lambda expressions."?

Comment: The advantage would be the metadata, in case there it were. If you look at [**`std`**][1] or **boost**, they all have such tools with the name `bind`. The idea was versatile in the absence of lambdas. Still in some cases `bind` can result in more readable code, but lambda increases optimizabiliy in various ways.


  [1]: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind